# how to initialize SQLite Database variable in my flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner in flutter, i want to use SQlite database using sqflite package in my Flutter App, when I declare the `_database` variable with this syntax `static Database _database;` i got a compilation error saying that i must initialize `_database`, and when i use this syntax `static Database? _database;`, i have a compilation error under `return _database` saying `A value of type 'Database?' can't be returned from the function 'database' because it has a return type of 'Future<Database>'.` and when i put `static late Database _database;` i have an error in execution saying `Error: LateInitializationError: Field '_database' has not been initialized.`
my code is

```
class AnnonceDataBase {

  AnnonceDataBase._();
  static final AnnonceDataBase instance = AnnonceDataBase._();
  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified it a bit but it works for you using a singleton to maintain the state of the database

```
class AnnonceDataBase {
  AnnonceDataBase._();
  static final AnnonceDataBase _instance = AnnonceDataBase._();
  static Database? _database;

  factory AnnonceDataBase() => _instance;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;
    _database = await initDB();
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> initDB() async {
    String table1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,key TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,name TEXT,phone NUMERIC)";
    String table2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,key TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,name TEXT,phone NUMERIC)";
    String path = await getDatabasesPath();
    // Open the database and save the reference.
    final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(
      // Set the path to the database. Note: Using the `join` function of the
      // plugin `path` is best practice to ensure the path is correct
      // built for each platform.
      p.join(path, 'admin.db'),
      // When the database is first created, create a table to store data
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        db.execute(table1);
        return db.execute(table2);
      },
      // Set the version. This runs the onCreate function and provides a
      // path to perform updates and downgrades on the database.
      version: 1,
    );

    return database;
  }
}
```

**You can use it like this**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    AnnonceDataBase._instance.database; //Initialize when loading the application or in the singleton
    super.initState();
  }
```

**Create a record**

```
Future<void> addData() async {
    Database database = AnnonceDataBase._database!;

    database.transaction((txn) async {
      await txn.rawInsert('INSERT INTO table1(id,key,name,phone) VALUES(?,?,?,?)', ["1", DateTime.now().toString(), "name", "+5555555"]);
    });
  }
```

**Read all records**

```
Future<void> readData() async {
    Database database = AnnonceDataBase._database!;

    List<Map> data = await database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table1");
    debugPrint("data: $data");
  }
```